# Getting intermittent 'google not defined' and other errors using maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My application makes api calls to the census and uses that data in combination with Google Maps API v3.  It works as expected much of the time, but I’m getting an intermittent error of ‘Initmap is not defined’, or ‘google is not defined’, or ‘TypeError: map.data.getFeatureById(...) is undefined’ without any discernible reason.
HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> 
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=KEY1234&callback=initMap" async defer
    ></script>
         <script src="js/mapfunc.js"></script>         
    </head>
    <body>    
            <div id="map"></div>
<script>var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 35, lng: -106}
    });
}</script> 

    </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
function loadMapShapes() {
    map.data.loadGeoJson('jsonya2.geojson', { idPropertyName: 'STATE' });
    variable = 'B01003_001E,NAME';  
    variable2 = ',B01001F_002E';     
    loadCensusData(variable);

}

function loadCensusData(variable) {
    // load the requested variable from the census API
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acs5/?get=' +
    variable + '&for=state:*&key=KEY123');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var censusData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        censusData.shift(); // the first row contains column names           

        censusData.forEach(function(row) { 
            censusMin = 0;
        censusMax = 36000000;
            var censusVariable = parseFloat(row[0]);             
            var stateName = row[1];

            var stateId = row[2];  
            // keep track of min and max values
            if (censusVariable < censusMin) {
              censusMin = censusVariable;
            }
            if (censusVariable > censusMax) {
              censusMax = censusVariable;
            }
            // update the existing row with the new data            
            coolid = map.data.getFeatureById(stateId);// <-- Here's where 
//I get the error most often: "TypeError: map.data.getFeatureById(...) is undefined"
            if (coolid !== undefined) {
                  map.data
        .getFeatureById(stateId)
        .setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);

                map.data
        .getFeatureById(stateId)
        .setProperty('census_variable1', stateName);
            }
            coolstate = map.data.getFeatureById(stateName);


        });
```

Again - this code works maybe 40% of the time, and throws one of the above-described errors the rest of the time.  I may notice an increase in errors during the day but can't be sure.

**Thanks a lot for any thoughts**, here's a link to a live version of this code with census and google maps API calls: 
http://dukecitydigital.com/c1/

Comment: move the `<script>` which includes the maps-API after the `<script>` where you define `initMap`

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle - I've done as you say but I still get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined' sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadGeoJson` runs asynchronously, use the callback of loadGeoJson to execute further functions which depend on the result of loadGeoJson:

```
function loadMapShapes() {
  variable = 'B01003_001E,NAME';  
  variable2 = ',B01001F_002E'; 

  map.data.loadGeoJson('jsonya2.geojson', { idPropertyName:'STATE'}, function(){
    loadCensusData(variable);
  });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks a lot Doc

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I am using to avoid 'undefined' error:

```
// update the existing row with the new data
if (typeof(map.data.getFeatureById(stateId)) != "undefined") {
  map.data
    .getFeatureById(stateId)
    .setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks CBEK - I ended up having to wrap all my get feature by ID and set propertys in this as well.